# Adding header files to a node

Tags: ros, c++, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm trying to add C++ header files to a ROS node but when I do catkin_make it gives the following error:

```
    CMakeFiles/hello.dir/src/hello.cpp.o: In function `chatterCallback(boost::shared_ptr<std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
hello.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `sleepms(int)'
hello.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::SetCommand(int, int, int)'
hello.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::Disconnect()'
CMakeFiles/hello.dir/src/hello.cpp.o: In function `main':
hello.cpp:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::Connect(std::string)'
CMakeFiles/hello.dir/src/hello.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
hello.cpp:(.text+0x598): undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::RoboteqDevice()'
hello.cpp:(.text+0x5a7): undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::~RoboteqDevice()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/nouf/catkin_ws/devel/lib/roboteq_motor/hello] Error 1
make[1]: *** [roboteq_motor/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

The header files are under include/PKG_NAME

This is the .cpp node:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "roboteq_motor/RoboteqDevice.h"
#include "roboteq_motor/ErrorCodes.h"
#include "roboteq_motor/Constants.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

using namespace std;
int status;
RoboteqDevice device;
void chatterCallback( const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg){
  sleepms(10);

    cout<<"- SetCommand(_GO, 1, 1)...";
    if((status = device.SetCommand(_GO, 1, 700)) != RQ_SUCCESS)
        cout<<"failed --> "<<status<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"succeeded."<<endl;

    device.Disconnect();
 }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "hello");
ros::NodeHandle nh;
    string response = "";

    status = device.Connect("/dev/ttyACM0");

    if(status != RQ_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout<<"Error connecting to device: "<<status<<"."<<endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Wait 10 ms before sending another command to device

ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("chatter", 1000, chatterCallback);
ros::spin();
    return 0;
```

This is CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(roboteq_motor)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)
catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  LIBRARIES roboteq_motor
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
 install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
 )
add_executable(hello src/hello.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

SOLUTION:
I changed this line

```
add_executable(hello src/hello.cpp)
```

to this

```
add_executable(hello src/hello.cpp src/RoboteqDevice.cpp)
```

THANK YOU ALL

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204671/adding-header-files-to-a-node/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-03-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-11**:
Btw: these are linker errors (missing symbols), not compiler errors (missing includes).

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-03-11**:
What are the missing symbols?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-11**:\

> hello.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::SetCommand(int, int, int)'

etc. Those are symbols the [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) cannot find. They are *not* errors from the [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler).

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-03-11**:
so what do you suggest as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you need to change

```
target_link_libraries(hello ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

for

```
target_link_libraries(hello ${catkin_LIBRARIES} roboteq_motor )
```

.

Note that:

```
catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  LIBRARIES roboteq_motor
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

makes packages that depend on this package implicitly linking their executables / libs against the roboteq_motor library but for the execs/libs in  this you still need to add the lib to `target_link_libraries`

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-11**:
@Wolf: there is no `add_library(..)` anywhere in the `CMakeLists.txt`, so `hello` cannot be linked against it. *If* `roboteq_motor` is an actual library, but is external, then the `roboteq_motor` pkg should be added to the `find_package(catkin ..)`. Otherwise, add the `.cpp` to `add_executable(..)`.

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-03-11**:
roboteq_motor is not a library. It's the current package name

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-03-11**:
Then   `LIBRARIES roboteq_motor` in your CMakeLists.txt up there makes no sense! Anyway you need to define the functions declared in your roboteq_motor/RoboteqDevice.h etc. headers anywhere and have to link this against your hello.cpp (as other src of lib)